# How to identify i come from which button

Tags: ios, swift

These both button shows same ViewController.

ViewController1.swift

```
@objc func btnEdit()
{
    print("Edit")
    let editDeptt = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Add Department") as! AddDepartmentVC
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(editDeptt, animated: true)
}

@IBAction func btnNewDeptt(_ sender: Any)
{
    let addDepttVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Add Department") as! AddDepartmentVC

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addDepttVC, animated: true)
}
```

ViewController2.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

      //How to identify i come from which button
}
```

Comment: Set **button.tag** , Thats it.

Comment: set Button1.tag=1, Button2.tag=2.. same as @iDeveloper said

Comment: combine @iDeveloper's comment and vacawama's answer. You will know which button tapped while loading the ViewController2.

Answer (score 2):

Add a property to your `AddApartmentVC` called `action` and set it before you push the view controller.

First create an enum:

```
enum Action {
    case edit, newDept, unknown
}
```

Then define this property in your `AddApartmentVC`:

```
var action = Action.unknown
```

Then in your buttons' actions, set the property to the desired value:

```
editDeptt.action = .edit
```

or

```
addDepttVC.action = .newDept
```

Finally, in `viewDidLoad()`, check the value:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    switch(action) {
    case .edit:
         // do something for edit
    case .newDept
         // create a new Dept
    case .unknown
         print("what am I doing here?")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an instance variable name `identify` in your `AddDepartmentVC` and pass set the value of the same from your current VC like this

```
let editDeptt = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Add Department") as! AddDepartmentVC
editDeptt.identify = "button1"
```

Then you can push it and check the variable in `AddDepartmentVC`

Answer (score 0):

In `ViewController2`.swift, declare one variable like this

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController{
   let var originTag: Int = 0
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if originTag == 0
    {
        // come from button 1 - btnEdit
    }
    else
    {
        // come from button 2 - btnNewDeptt
    }
}
```

In `ViewController 1`, set `originTag` like this.

```
@objc func btnEdit()
{
    print("Edit")
    let editDeptt = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Add Department") as! AddDepartmentVC
    editDeptt.originTag = 0
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(editDeptt, animated: true)
}

@IBAction func btnNewDeptt(_ sender: Any)
{
    let addDepttVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Add Department") as! AddDepartmentVC
    addDepttVC.originTag = 1
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addDepttVC, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign a tag for button -

```
Button1.tag=1
Button2.tag=2
```

Then check your button -

```
func onClickButton(sender: UIButton){
switch(sender.tag){
    case 101 :
        print("I am from button 1")
    default :
        print("I am from button 2")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use following it's perfectly working for you.

Take one public variable above class like below in Viewcontroller1.Swift

```
public var btnComingFrom = "first"

@objc func btnEdit()
{

   btnComingFrom = "first"

    print("Edit")
    let editDeptt = 
 self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Add Department") 
as! AddDepartmentVC
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(editDeptt, animated: true)
}

@IBAction func btnNewDeptt(_ sender: Any)
{
   btnComingFrom = "second"

    let addDepttVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Add Department") as! AddDepartmentVC

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addDepttVC, animated: true)
}
```

ViewController2.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

      if btnComingFrom == "first"
      {
       print("you are coming from first button")
      }
      if btnComingFrom == "second"
      {
       print("you are coming from second button")
      }
}
```